# Large outgoing traffic to IP 17.248.173.17

Tags: macbook-pro, network

I observed, that my MacBook Pro 13" from 2017, usually 2 days in week, is sending large number of packets to IP address 17.248.173.17. It is Apple's IP address, but I would like to stop it. I have disabled analytics for Apple etc. but it is still sending some data outside. Could someone help me, how to solve this problem? In activity monitor -> network, there isn't any process with these number of packets.

Comment: Do you have iCloud activated ?

Comment: What do you consider "large"?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to monitor and block outgoing traffic from your Mac is by installing and using Little Snitch:

https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html

You can use the free trial period to try to discover what program is the source of those data transfers. After that the program comes at a cost.